# Share object instance between multiple forms

Tags: .net, winforms

I have multi-form application and I need one instance of **MyClass()** be accessible from each form. 
Where should I put it?

Make it public for form1 and then user in other forms **Form1.MyClassInstance** or what is the best way?

Comment: Do you have an application controller class or something like that? That would be the best place to put it in after making sure it is a singleton, if thats required for your functionality.

Comment: Are you using C# or VB.NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare the object you want to share as a [static](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) field:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public static object MyObject;
    //...
}
```

...or declare it as a static property:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private static object obj;
    public static object MyObject
    {
        get { return obj; } // read-only
    }
    //...
}
```

...and then you access it like this (in other classes):

```
object obj = Form1.MyObject;
```

However, if you have multiple instances of Form1, MyObject will be the same for all instances of Form1.

---

Another approach is setting the [Form.Owner](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.owner.aspx) property, by calling [Form.Show()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/szcefbbd.aspx):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public object MyObject; // no static required
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        f2.Show(this); // this sets the Form.Owner property on f2
    }
    //...
}
```

...and then you access it like this (in Form2):

```
Form1 f1 = (Form1)this.Owner;
object o = f1.MyObject;
```

The advantage here is that you can now access all public members of Form1, even though they are not declared static. But if you minimize/close Form1, Form2 will also be minimized/closed.

---

If you don't want to use static or Form.Owner, you can also pass a reference to Form1 instance as a parameter. For example, in Form2 you can write a constructor that takes Form1 as a parameter:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2(Form1 f1)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        object o = f1.MyObject; // access MyObject like this
    }
    //...
}
```

...and instantiate Form2 like this (in Form1):

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2(this);
```